# Go from Db Set to Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda

I have a

```
DbSet<People>
```

I am trying to get this into a

```
Dictionary<int, List<People>>
```

My class is

```
public People
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int Age { get; set; } //this is key of dictionary
}
```

I want to group by age. So age would be key with a list of everyone of the same age.
This is the call to get my list

```
var items = db.People.ToList();
```

I am trying to use the ToDictionary method, but I am not sure if this is the correct way to go. It seems like there should be a lambda statement to achieve this.

```
 Dictionary<int, List<People> myDictionary = items.ToDictionary(p => p.Age, p => People);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `GroupBy` first:

```
var myDictionary = items.GroupBy(p => p.Age)
                        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

You can also do that on context directly, to move grouping into DB instead of performing it within your application:

```
var myDictionary = db.People.GroupBy(p => p.Age)
                        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```